# Returning success or failure as well as result from function

Tags: python

Can you suggest for me a nice way to return to the client if the following function succeeds or not before the timeout is reached?

```
def until_true(func, condition, timeout):
    s = 0.05
    t = 0
    while t <= timeout:
        result = func()
        if condition(result): 
            return t, result
        time.sleep(s)
        t = t + s
    return result
```

With the current implementation you can test if it has failed by checking the len of the return value which is really ugly. If the function succeeds, I also wish to return the result and the time it took for the function to succeed. If it fails, I wish to return just the result.

Comment: you are returning sometime two values and sometime one value. Also need to define  `result` because if code in not go into while loop then it will raise NameError exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have your first return value as a *sentinel* to check if it is successful or not. That is

```
return (True, t, result)
```

And while accepting it at the calling side have it as `success, others, others2 = until_true(..)` so that you can test, `if success` ...

Similarly for the failed portion you can have

```
return (False, result)
```

Answer (score 2):

A more pythonic way would be to use [exceptions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#exceptions):

```
class TimeoutException(Exception):
    def __init__(self, result):
         self.result = result

def until_true(func, condition, timeout):
    [...]
    raise TimeoutException(result)

try:
    time_spent, result  = until_true([...])
except TimeoutException as exc:
    result = exc.result
```

Answer (score 0):

The typical pythonic way of reporting error conditions in python is via exceptions rather than return values. In this case you still want to return something, though, so the solution becomes a bit less clear cut. Still, you might want to go with something like this (not tested):

```
class Timeout(Exception): pass

def until_true(func, condition=bool, timeout=1.0, interval=0.05):
    t = 0
    while t <= timeout:
        result = func()
        if condition(result): 
            return t, result
        time.sleep(interval)
        t += interval
    raise Timeout(result)

try:
   t, result = until_true(func)
except Timeout as err:
   print "Oh no, timed out! But got result " + str(err.message)
```

I think this approach is better if timeouts usually shouldn't happen, and require some special action. Otherwise, a simple approach is to simply return `t`, result in any case, letting the caller check if `t` is greater than the timeout, or returning some special value for `t` upon timeout, or even using a third return value like the other answer.

(By the way, your logic assumes that `func` or `condition` take no time to execute. If they are time-consuming, `until_true` will end up running for longer than your timeout since you only count the time spent sleeping. A better approach would use `time.time()` or similar to check the actual elapsed time.)